# Access values of a list widget

Tags: lua, vlc

[VLC dev lua readme](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) documents the api for creating a list widget and adding values to it:

```
d:add_list( ... )
w:add_value( text, id )
```

How can I iterate over added values (i.e. all values available to be selected, *not* the current list widget selection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no api to access the list widget values. Instead of doing that directly, MVVM pattern can be used where we keep the list values in an array and sync the UI whenever we change its values:

```
function render()
    stuffWidget:clear()

    for k,v in pairs(stuffModel)do
        stuffWidget:add_value(v)
    end

end
```

[Lua documentation on tables](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.html) can then be used to operate on the array however we want